Can somebody explain how is this a square?
I have a wall that I am trying to add a window to, according to the coordinates and the edge lengths this is suppose to be a square, am I missing something essential in Blender settings because it really doesn't seem like a square to me


Your object's scale is probably not 1. Apply Scale with Ctrl+A ?

Yes that works! How couldn't I think about it?! Thanks a lot!
